# Confusing syntax for Welch's PSD method in Matlab

Tags: matlab

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html) does specify the use of a lot of arguments but I find it confusing at best. Some of the given syntax are:

```
pxx = pwelch(x,window,noverlap,nfft)
[pxx,f] = pwelch(x,window,noverlap,f,fs)
```

where fs is the sampling freq. Welch method (for finding the Power Spectral Density, PSD) divides an input signal of length N into K segments, each of length L and overlap D. It also uses a window. I'd like to know what syntax allows me to specify L, D, window, nfft (if needed), fs (if needed), and get an output like [pxx, f]. It seems this is not possible for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
[pxx,f] = pwelch(x,window,noverlap,nfft,fs);
```

where `noverlap` is what you refer to as `D` and `nfft` and `fs` are optional.
For the `window` argument you have two options. Either you set `window` to be the segment length (i.e. `L`) and then the window used is the default (Hamming I think), or you specify a custom window of length `L` (the segment length is taken from the window length)